# Error: EDID Checksum is invalid when logging in to Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

Let me start off by saying that I'm a complete Linux noob. I've played around the GUI and the command line, but I've done nothing of the sort that I can do on Windows.

I'm handling a client that makes use of Linux, Apache, Pear, and PHP, along with Oracle 10g. Due to complications, I'd like to recreate their setup - any errors I might encounter along the way are to be documented, and solved. That way, I can learn the ins and outs.

However, I did not expect that merely installing and running Linux would be such a pain already. I'm using Fedora, the latest available version, x86_64. After downloading the ISO, burning it to a DVD, and booting up from it, I was greeted by the 'Live System'. After picking out whatever is the easiest from a variety of options, I was finally allowed to install it to the hard drive.

A few minutes later, it says it is done, and it will use the HDD-installed OS from then on. Seeing no option or command to reboot on that blank Fedora screen, I just flicked the reset switch on my PC.

When it came back on, first, it showed me a boot screen with two options:

- Fedora, with Linux 3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64
- Fedora, with Linux 0-rescue-7725dfc225d14958a625ddaaaea5962b

I chose the first one, as I have no idea what the second one is. It greeted me to a log in screen. Upon entering my password, it shows a black screen, with the following error:

**Error: EDID Checksum is invalid, remainder is 128**

There are some numbers and text underneath, and I'm not sure if there's anything at the top - for some reason, that entire error, including the cursor, only occupies the top left of my screen.

And it just stops there.

I have no idea how to deal with this. Can anyone help?

I'm using the following:

- Fedora Live Desktop x86-64 Release 19
- Intel Celeron, 2.66Ghz
- 1GB of RAM
- Asrock 775i65g
- No dedicated graphics card

Thanks.

Comment: The error message has to do with the acceptable resolution information your monitor sends to your video card.  It may or may not be related to the problem.  You can _probably_ access a command-line interface by pressing <ctrl>-<alt>-<F2> (it may take a few seconds to respond).  From there you can log in and run `dmesg` or look in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see if there are any interesting errors.

Comment: Thank you. CTRL+ALT+F2 did bring up the command line, and I was able to log in. I didn't see any errors in '/var/log/Xorg.0.log/' via 'less', but I didn't know what to look for. I did see something about video, and resolution and drivers and stuff. 'dmesg' did turn up a lot of EDID Checksum is invalid errors.

Comment: I should add that I'm using the motherboard's dedicated VGA. Also updated some information in the question that might be useful, regarding boot options.

Comment: If you have another monitor, try booting with that to see if that is the problem.  Also, check that you have the intel graphics driver: post the output of `rpm -qa | grep intel`.  Really, here I'm just stabbing in the dark; maybe post the full log messages to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so we can have a more detailed look.

Comment: I replaced the monitor; same thing. Also, my apologies on the lack of information - I'm truly clueless when it comes to Linux CLI. Anyway, the result of 'rpm -qa | grep intel' is 'xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.21.8-1.fc19.x86_64'. As for pastebin, how do I do that without a GUI? Again, thanks.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about lacking GUI access.  I'm guessing the best way forward is to try the installation again.  I've checked the documentation and you shouldn't need to do a hard-reboot.  When it's time to reboot, a button is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment and your description, you may not have completed the installation fully.  When Fedora 19 is done being installed, the installer (anaconda) shows a Reboot button:

[image]

Perhaps try re-installing Fedora from the DVD.  You can follow the [Quick Installation Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Installation_Quick_Start_Guide/index.html) to make sure things are proceeding normally.

Comment: Well, at least that got me to log in, though the only thing I'm getting is a grey screen with the Fedora logo on the bottom. Another question for another time. Thanks.